# PowerShell command output truncates decimal of float values

Tags: windows, disk-space, remote

I am using the following command to check space on remote server:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName computer-name | Select Name,@{n="Free";e={[math]::trun
cate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}, @{n="Total Size";e={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}
```

It outputs:

```
Name Free Total Size
---- ---- ----------
C:     13         59
D:      0          0
```

However, the actual space is: 10.5 free from 59.8. It's like it's using int, not float. Anyone know how can I change it in order to show the real float values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. It seems I need to use **abs** instead of the **truncate** function.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName computer-name | Select Name,@{n="Free";e={[math]::abs(
$_.freespace / 1GB)}}, @{n="Total Size";e={[math]::abs($_.size / 1GB)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

or Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName computer-name | Select Name,@{n="Free";e={[($*.freespace / 1GB) -as [int]}}, @{n="Total Size";e={$*.size / 1GB -as [int])}}

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting). Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something really new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them.